# Finding the volume bounded between cylinder $x^2 +y^2-2ax=0$ and paralaboloid $x^2+y^2=2az$ and $xy$ plane.

Tags: integration, polar-coordinates, volume

I came across this question in double integral.

**What I did**:
I converted the equation $x^2+y^2-2ax=0$ to polar form $r=2acos\theta$ and $z=\frac{x^2+y^2}{2a}$ to $z = \frac{r^2}{2a}$ thus got the double integral as:

$$\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2} \int_{0}^{2acos\theta}\frac{r^2}{2a}\cdot r\cdot dr\cdot d\theta$$ which I calculated to be $\frac{3\pi a^3}{4}$.

**The problem is**:The  answer given in the book is $3\pi a^3$. I can't figure out where I did wrong.

Comment: Your answer is perfectly right. I just cross-checked it.

Comment: The the polar transformation and limit change correct?

Comment: Yes, it is perfectly fine.